# How to disable the Tracked Pose Driver in a Unity VR Application?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I need to write a VR application that disables HMD positional tracking for a specific situation and then reenable it again.

In the UI it is a simple as ticking and unticking the TrackedPoseDriver shown in the picture below.

How can I do that via Scripting?

I assume I need to use the enabled property of a game object. But I don't know how to grab a hold of this GameObject (or Component).

EDIT: In case this was clear this is GameObject/Component associated to the main camera.

[image: What I want to Disable]

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So I was able to do It.

What I did is I search MonoBehaviour Based Components on the camera and then cast it to a MonoBehaviour once I found the right one. And then used the enabled property. Like this:

```
    Component[] components = Camera.main.GetComponents(typeof(MonoBehaviour));
    bool found = false;
    foreach(Component component in components) {
        string name = component.ToString();     
        MonoBehaviour mb = (MonoBehaviour) component;
        if (name.Contains(TRACK_POSE_DRIVER_NAME)){
            mbTrackingPose = mb;
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
```

The unique string that the toString() method provided was somethign like (I don't have it on hand) "Main Camera (Unity.XR.TrackedPoseDriver)". So I just made sure that the string had the "TrackedPoseDriver" and stored that as a MonoBehaviour.

I hope this helps someone else.