# Accessing centerEyeRotation (face tracking) from TrackedPoseDriver in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arkit

I am using ARKit within Unity to implement face tracking on an iOS device. Face tracking is working fine, and I want to access the real-time centerEyeRotation measurements produced by the face tracking. Following this helpful [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74890872/how-to-disable-the-tracked-pose-driver-in-a-unity-vr-application/)
I used the code below to try and at least access the TrackedPoseDriver, but I keep getting back the data from the Main Camera (the game object that this script is attached to). Any idea how I can access the centerEyeRotation data?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class getTrackedPoseDriver : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool found;
    MonoBehaviour mbTrackingPose;
    MonoBehaviour mb;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Component[] components = Camera.main.GetComponents(typeof(MonoBehaviour));
        found = false;
        foreach (Component component in components)
        {
            string name = component.ToString();
            mb = (MonoBehaviour)component;
            if (name.Contains("UnityEngine.InputSystem.XR.TrackedPoseDriver"))
            {
                mbTrackingPose = mb;
                found = true;
                Debug.Log(found);
                Debug.Log(mbTrackingPose.name);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(mbTrackingPose.transform.rotation.y);
    }
}
```

I also attempted a different approach (see below). This script (attached to the Main Camera) does confirm XRNode.CenterEye as valid, but device.TryGetFeatureValue fails to get centerEyePosition.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR;

public class centerEyeRotation : MonoBehaviour
{

    Quaternion centEyeRot;
    Vector3 centEyePos;

    //Quaternion rotation;
    bool tryGet;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        tryGet = false;

        InputDevice device = InputDevices.GetDeviceAtXRNode(XRNode.CenterEye);

        if (device.isValid)
        {
            Debug.Log("Device is valid");
            if (device.TryGetFeatureValue(CommonUsages.centerEyePosition, out centEyePos))
                tryGet = true;
            Debug.Log("centerEyePosition found");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I may have solved the problem via a different route; the project instantiates an AR face prefab object at runtime. By attaching a script to this prefab I was able to report the transform of the prefab, which seems to be giving me the orientation data I need.